# How to get the gdata address for a youtube channel?

Tags: youtube, youtube-api, gdata, android-youtube-api

Hey Developer's I am working on an android app. I see this gdata.youtube kind of address in tutorials. I need to get one for my channel. Please how do i go about it. 
Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The gdata links are from YouTube Data API v2.0 which is deprecated. You should look into Youtube Data API v3.0.
Here is how to get started: https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/

If you just want to get information about your channel use this link:
https://content.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/channels?part=snippet&mine=true&key=YOURAPIKEY
Replace YOURAPIKEY with the public access API key from https://console.developers.google.com/project